# Attributed text in UITextView causing a crash

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, nsattributedstring

This is my code to display an attributed string in a UITextView

```
NSMutableAttributedString *recipeString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
    [recipeString appendAttributedString:string1];
    [recipeString appendAttributedString:string2];
    [array addObject:recipeString];
```

This code is inside a `for` loop. `string1` and `string2` are `NSMutableAttributedString`s.

After that:

```
self.textView.text = [array objectAtIndex:self.appDelegate.selectedCell];
```

The text view is an `IBOutlet`.

It crashes with this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteAttributedString _isCString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e866f0'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this crash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to use the `attributedText` property of `UITextView`:

```
self.textView.attributedText = [array objectAtIndex:self.appDelegate.selectedCell];
```

Answer (score 0):

For future users:

`-[NSConcreteAttributedString mutableString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

this may also be caused by if in the above instance `string1` or `string2` is `nil`